# boost::shared_ptr crashes when application is ending

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have following classes:

```
    class Session
    {
    public:      
      Session(boost::asio::io_service &io_service)
        : socket_(io_service)
      {
      }
    }



class ConnectionHandler: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<ConnectionHandler> {
         boost::shared_ptr<Session> mySession;
                //blah blah
  Broker &theBroker;
  public:    
 //....    
 ConnectionHandler(
       boost::shared_ptr<Session> session_ ,/*....*/);   
       ~ConnectionHandler(){
        //crash happens here  
        std::cout << "Killing ConnectionHandler " << this << " " << shared_from_this();
                }    
//.... 
};  



class ClientHandler: public EventListener {   
Broker & broker;   
//... 
public:   
ClientHandler(Broker &);
   boost::shared_ptr<ConnectionHandler > cnnHandler;
//...   
virtual ~ClientHandler();
//... 
};
```

(session is member of ConnectionHandler and ConnectionHandler is a member of ClientHandler)

well, the objects are created like this:

```
xxx::some_function()
{
//...
boost::shared_ptr<ClientHandler> clientEntry(new ClientHandler(broker));
boost::shared_ptr<ConnectionHandler > cnnHandler(
                new ConnectionHandler(request.session_,broker
            //...blah blah
            )
                    );
//and now assign it
clientEntry->cnnHandler = cnnHandler;

//and then insert it to a nested std::map container somewhere else
broker.insertClientList(clientEntry);
}//and clientEntry & cnnHandler go out of scope
```

The application runs fine but in the end it crashes saying:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_weak_ptr> >'
      what():  tr1::bad_weak_ptr
```

Another note: I marked the destructor where the application crashes. If I hadn't entered a std::cout, the application would crash around ~session()

May I know where I am doing it wrong? and how may i solve it?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should never calls `shared_from_this` in d-tor.

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/147

> This behavior is by design. Since the destructor will destroy 
> the object, it is not safe to create a shared_ptr to it as it will 
> become dangling once the destructor ends.

Comment: Or the c'tor for that matter. Also a common mistake when using asio.

Comment: @ForEveR ok,thanks for that. Next, as I mentioned in my question, even if I remove the cout line, I will still get the crash. (actually I had put the cout line trying to find the cause of the crash)

Comment: @rahman There is too little information about crash. Give full information about session in this case.